# Find the name and IMDB rating of all the movies which contain either 1 or, 2 or, 3 or.... 20 characters in their name

Tags: mysql, sql, xampp

I have a `movie` table inside my `Movie_Info` database which content `Movie_Name`, `Movie_ID`, `IMDB_Rating` etc fields. Like this:

[image]

Now I want to fetch the name and IMDB rating of all the movies which contain total 1~20 numbers of characters in their name.

What should be the `SQL` query for it?

Comment: the [length function](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_length.asp) ?

Comment: @Andrew The LENGTH() function returns the length of a string. But how can I check if the length is in between `1 to 20` or not?

Comment: `where length(your_column) between 1 and 20`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the full query you need:

```
select 
   name, IMDB_rating
from Movie_Info
where length(Movie_name) between 1 and 20
```